# populating variable value dynamically in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have four tables as below : I want to insert the variable value v_col  into the table test.This variable name is stored in another table test_lkp.when i try to run the code i am getting an error. How to achieve this.

```
DROP TABLE TEST ;
DROP TABLE TEST_LKP;
DROP TABLE TEST_REF;
DROP TABLE TEST_Q;
CREATE TABLE TEST (COL VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE TEST_LKP (COL VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE TEST_REF (VAL VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE TEST_Q (ENAME VARCHAR2(10));
INSERT INTO TEST_LKP VALUES ('v_col');
INSERT INTO TEST_REF VALUES ('ENAME');
INSERT INTO TEST_Q VALUES ('TOM');
INSERT INTO TEST_Q VALUES ('JIM');
INSERT INTO TEST_Q VALUES ('MARK');

COMMIT;
```

Actual code :

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare

   v_col  VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
      SELECT VAL INTO v_col FROM TEST_REF;  
    dbms_output.put_line(v_col);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
 ' INSERT  INTO TEST  SELECT '|| V_COL ||' FROM TEST_Q ' ;

END;
/
```

expectation is to build the insert statement dynamically through the look up table so that if any change in the columns can be handled through the look up table rather than modifying the script.
   To achieve i have created the look up table TEST_LKP with the same structure as TEST and inserting values as V_COL.

This is what i tried

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
   v_col  VARCHAR2(30);
   q VARCHAR2(1000);
  CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT
      'INSERT  INTO TEST '
      ||   
    'SELECT ' || COL || ' FROM TEST_Q '  DMLS   
    FROM TEST_LKP;
  BEGIN
  SELECT val INTO v_col FROM TEST_REF;  
    dbms_output.put_line(v_col);
  FOR i IN c1
   loop
  dbms_output.put_line(i.DMLS);
  execute immediate i.dmls;
  end loop;
END;
/
```

erorr :

```
Error report -
ORA-00904: "V_COL": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 17
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:   
*Action:
ENAME
INSERT  INTO TEST SELECT v_col FROM TEST_Q
```

Expected :

```
i want v_col to be replaced with ENAME as

    INSERT  INTO TEST SELECT ENAME FROM TEST_Q
```

any solution for this ?

Comment: what wrong i am doing here?

Comment: The variable's scope is restricted to the block where it's defined only and cannot be used in a dynamic statement. That's because `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` runs it in sql scope where the variables declared locally are not visible. Why are you messing up things  with such a horrible design? Keep it straightforward. Tell us why you ended up here.

Comment: expectation is to build the insert statement dynamically through the look up table so that if any change in the columns can be handled through the look up table rather than modifying the script. To achieve i have created the look up table TEST_LKP with the same structure as TEST and inserting values as V_COL. What could be the best possible way to build and execute the query dynamically without changing the script?

Comment: @KaushikNayak : is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: To build the insert statement dynamically, you may refer to the column names from  user_tab_columns/all_tab_columns

Comment: how to use the variable v_col ?